# GTK4 Library Build fails to include dialog functions

Tags: gnome, raspberry-pi4, gtk4

I am trying to build a version of GTK4.4.2 on my Pi4/Bullseye that includes Vulkan support.  I have downloaded GTK4.4.2 from gnome.org.  I *believe* I have installed all its dependencies (glib, vulkan, etc.).  I set the proper meson config params, run meson, run ninja, and run ninja install.  All good... builds and installs fine.  I check the install with pkg-config and it reports GTK4.4.2.  I build my own C program and check the GTK version through it and it too reports v4.4.2.

However, when I attempt to use GTK functions like gtk_alert_dialog_new or gtk_file_dialog_new that were released in v4.1+ I get implicit declaration errors on those functions implying they are not found in the library?  My code has many other GTK4 specific functions in it that compile just fine.  What am I missing?

(I can provide the meson-log.txt and install-log.txt files, but they seem like an awful lot to include here.)

Thanks in advance!

I've uninstalled, rebuilt, and re-installed the library with no change in behavior.
I've read through the meson and install logs, but without knowing what to look for I was not able to find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [`gtk_alert_dialog_new()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/ctor.AlertDialog.new.html), you'll find your answer: this is API that only got added in GTK 4.10 (which released about a month ago).

Note that you shouldn't handle version numbers like you do decimal numbers:

- when talking about versions: 4.10 > 4.1
- when talking about numbers: 4.10 == 4.1